# Определить сколько чисел в массиве начинаются с цифр '20'

Tags: c++, массивы

Допустим есть заполнение вектора рандомными четырехзначными числами

```
vector <int> arr;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    arr.push_back(1000 + (rand() % static_cast<int>(9999 - 1000 + 1)));
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

И нужно найти сколько чисел начинаются с '20..'

Comment: Нужно обойти массив, проверять каждое число, и увеличивать счетчик. Что из этого не получается?

Comment: Вопрос в том, как проверить это каждое число.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверка для четырехзначных:

```
if (arr[i]/100 == 20)
```